# Extending a string on c#

Tags: c#

I learn c# and I have a question about strings. There is a string with full of '1's and '0's. But I don't know its length. I get the length of string with while loop. But if length is less than 8, I need to complete its length to 8 with '0's. I tried to declare a new string with 7 '0's. And did this: (where a is my string and zeroAdd is the '0's I want to add.

```
 if(length<8)
 {
     for(i=length;i<8;i++)
     a[i]=zeroAdd[8-length];

     a[i]='\0';
 }
```

but it didn't work. I can't use the shortcuts I saw on the internet and wanted to ask you. I would appreciate if you could explain it to me like this. Thanks in advance. Have a good one.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the inbuilt padding?

```
string myString = "1101";
var result = myString.PadLeft(8,'0');
```

Gives you:

```
00001101
```

To do it with a loop (and right-padding), you can do this:

```
string myString = "1101";
while (myString.Length < 8)
    myString += "0";
```

Comment: First of all thanks Rob, but I need to add the '0's to the end. I am sorry, I forgot to write it. It is a part of my task to use if statements or for, do-while loops etc.

Comment: @Sagopa For the future (not for this assigment), you can also use `.PadRight`. I will update my answer with a solution using a loop

Comment: No worries mate :)